# How to verify notify.js alert in selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, notifications, gettext

I want to verify the text of notification message which has code like this:

```
<div class="notifyjs-corner" style="top: 0px; left: 45%;">
  <div class="notifyjs-wrapper notifyjs-hidable">
    <div class="notifyjs-arrow" style=""/>
      <div class="notifyjs-container" style="">
        <div class="notifyjs-bootstrap-base notifyjs-bootstrap-success">
          <span data-notify-text="">Payment Created Successfully</span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My selenium code is:

```
String notify = BrowserSetup
  .driver
  .findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,
    'Payment Created Successfully')]"))
  .getText();
System.out.println(notify);
```

The value in `String notify` is empty.

**Question**

How can I get text of the notification?

For reference: [notify.js](https://notifyjs.com/)

Comment: Try once as : `BrowserSetup.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.notifyjs-bootstrap-base.notifyjs-bootstrap-success")).getText();` and let me know..:)

Comment: It is throwing no such element exception

Comment: Could you tell me when this alert become visible??

Comment: Actually it is visible after a popup closes .

Comment: Then you need to implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until this element visible as `new WebDriverWait(BrowserSetup.driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.notifyjs‌​-bootstrap-base.noti‌​fyjs-bootstrap-succe‌​ss"))).getText();` and let me know..

Comment: I have used this. But it is throwing timeout exception now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122504/discussion-between-kanu-priya-and-saurabh-gaur).

Comment: Did you tried with this code after closing popup??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find element by `Css Selector`

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".notifyjs-bootstrap-base.notifyjs-bootstrap-success>span"))).getText();

        String notify= BrowserSetup.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".notifyjs-bootstrap-base.notifyjs-bootstrap-success>span")).getText();
        System.out.println(notify);
```

It is working when I `find element by cssSelector`